# Media print not coming correctly when print using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to print a div using the following `javascript` code as follows:

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementById(curid);

    var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');

    newWin.document.open();

    newWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="css/print.css"></head><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');



    newWin.document.close();

    setTimeout(function () {
        newWin.close();
    }, 10);
```

Print.css as follows:

```
@media print {
        font-size:10px;
        font-family: Calibri;

    }
```

Print div style is as follows:
`font-size:8pt;font-family: Calibri`;

When I see the div it comes correctly. But when I print the font-size comes as **12 font-size** which I checked in open office.

I tried to change the media-print attributes but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be as follows:

```
@media print {
    body{
        font-size:10px;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }
}
```

The stuff beteen the { } of your media query will only be 'run' when the media query matches. So before you didn't have valid CSS between these { }.

Comment: not working. I have even gave a background color. Not working.  Am I calling print.css correcly in js for printing?

Comment: @media print not working at all. I even tried a background-color as well but not coming in print.